# Application got stuck when using HidP_GetValueCaps() second times

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, usb, hid

I reference a C# windows form application(**Program_Ref**), try to write a new program(**Program_A**) with similar functions.

One of function calls 'Find Device', which means using vendor id and product id to find specific usb device.

Both of two apps work fine when launch on, but when I try to use function 'Find Device' again, my whole application(include UI) will get stuck.

On the contrary, the sample application still work fine.

I doubt that the problem is from **[STAThread]**.
Here's the difference between two programs:

**Ref.cs**

```
public class Ref
{
  internal  static FrmMain FrmMy;

  public static void Main() 
  { 
    FrmMy = new FrmMain(); 
    Application.Run(FrmMy); 
  }
}
```

**FrmMain.cs**

```
internal class FrmMain : Form 
{
  // Other codes...

  [STAThread]
  internal static void Main() { Application.Run(new FrmMain()); }
}
```

And following codes is mine:

**A.cs**

```
public class A
{
  [STAThread]
  static void Main()
  {
      Application.EnableVisualStyles();
      Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
      Application.Run(new Form1());
  }
}
```

**Form1.cs**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form 
{
   // Other codes...
   // There's no entry point
}
```

I can't figure out the difference of them, and how to solve the problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately, I found a solution that fixes my problem, sharing with you.

Here's the solution I found:
[What is this error: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8703533/what-is-this-error-system-runtime-interopservices-comexception)

But there's a little difference in my Program:
[Project Properties -> Build -> Prefer 32-bit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MkVua.png)

I cancel the selection of 'Prefer 32-bit' option, and the application works fined.
Hope the solution can help someone, thanks.